Need for volumes in Databricks
Why do we need Volumes when we can access the location using external locations? The doc says that it is to add governance, but we can already govern using external locations. So, why add another layer of governance? I am guessing that instead of giving access to the entire external location, we can provide access to a specific subfolder of the location using volumes.

External Locations are the administrative component while Volumes are the front-facing object that final users use. Volumes are at the same level as Tables while External Locations are one level below.
External locations map an authentication mechanism (Storage Credentials) with a specific ADLS container/path. This is a task that an administrator should setup. Then, the administrator gives permissions to the final users to use the External Location to create Volumes or Tables. A Volume is used for unstructured or semistructured data while a table is used for tabular data.
(I work for Databricks)

So, can this happen that a person does not have access to entire external location but a subfolder to it using volumes. Basically, no access to external location but access to volume. I want to test it but don't have the administrative access. Can you provide some screenshots to show if it's possible?

Yes you can. You can just create a Volume in a subfolder of the External Location, and give READ FILES access to a user on that Volume

Okay. But what benefit do volumes bring? When given access to external location (to create tables or volumes over it), why would I create volume instead of directly using the path?

You shouldn't ask yourself that question :) They have been built for different purposes. You should not give access to the external location directly because it is an admin-only construct. But to answer your question, with External Locations you don't have FUSE so only Spark (and pyspark) can access to files in it. If you try to access with a standard python library like os (but all others as well) it won't work.

Volumes can also be used to store non-data files such as Libraries, configuration, and so on.
Also, if an end user wants to upload sample data to Cloud storage for some ad-hoc tasks, this will be the safest way, as volume points to a specific cloud location and is Governed.
Opening the entire cloud backend is risky and not advisable for end users.

"Volumes can also be used to store non-data files such as Libraries, configuration, and so on." You mean that they can be used to upload, right? Because they aren't containers themselves

You can upload using UI or copy using copy commands. They are folders inside a bucket or Azure container.

I meant that the word "used to store" is incorrect, it should be "used to upload". So, you have one point and that is they can be used to upload. This is a valid point but doesn't seem to be why we need volumes instead of storage locations. I will wait for others to answer. Will accept yours if couldn't find anything better.

Volumes are siblings to tables, views, and other objects organized under a schema in Unity Catalog.
While tables provide governance over tabular datasets, volumes add governance over non-tabular datasets.
You can use volumes to store and access files in any format, including structured, semi-structured, and unstructured data.
